# How do I use/retrieve the C3 scale function post generate?

Tags: d3.js, charts, c3

I am using C3 to generate a chart and have found it necessary to dig into the underlying D3 constructs to supplement its functionality.  I'm at an impasse and need to draw a region that is both limited by the x values and the y values but the "regions" functionality of C3 only allows one or the other. So, I need to draw on the C3-generated chart a rect at the appropriate location but using the scale functions to determine the X/Y values of the new rect. Is there any way to do this with C3 or underlying D3 library?

Comment: have you seen this http://c3js.org/samples/region.html example.

Comment: Yes but that does not accomplish drawing ONLY the intersection of the X region and the Y region.  I have come up with a solution using classes so that I can create both the X and Y region, have C3 draw them for me at the correct coordinates and then limit the Y region by the X region's x value and width and then remove the X region.  It was a round-about time, consuming solution, but it seems to be working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access the scale function from the chart.internal (chart.internal.x and chart.internal.y). You'll probably need the margins too (otherwise your positions will be offset by that much)

Here's how you draw a rectangle from point (0 index, 100) to (2 index, 400)

```
var rect = chart.internal.svg.append("rect")
    .attr('fill', 'rgba(255, 9, 0, 0.1)')
    .attr("x", chart.internal.x(0) + chart.internal.margin.left)
    .attr("y", chart.internal.y(400) + chart.internal.margin.top)
    .attr("width", chart.internal.x(2) - chart.internal.x(0))
    .attr("height", chart.internal.y(100) - chart.internal.y(400));
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/hehpy91o/

Comment: I switched the X axis to a timeseries (as that's what I really need (forgot to mention that in first post)) and I'm getting some weird results of C3 not actually plotting at my exact X value--seems to be off by a certain number of pixels but can't figure what that value is.  We are already compensating for left margin, but it doesn't see to be enough.  http://jsfiddle.net/gyvnffmw/

Comment: I think it's something to do with how the date string is being parsed. I put in the date parts and it looks ok - http://jsfiddle.net/dd90g345/ - note that the month is 0 indexed.

Comment: super helpful, was missing the margins piece

Comment: @potatopeelings You saved my day!