# c3 getting bar length and width or x/y coordinates

Tags: bar-chart, c3.js

I was looking into a using c3 as a rendering library. Explorer the API, I found a requirement that might not be doable with c3.

What I intend to is create custom layover of a c3 bar chart as I want to be able to add customization to the axis labels and other aspects of the chart. To do so, I need to be able to access the width and height(or the x/y coordinates) of each bar so I can align my overlay correctly. I don't see a way from the c3 API to get this information.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can access a chart's x and y scales via its 'internal' property to calculate points from the same data that was used to generate the bar chart as per this answer -->

[How do I use/retrieve the C3 scale function post generate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31144955/how-do-i-use-retrieve-the-c3-scale-function-post-generate)

2. If you want the coordinates of the rendered bars you can select them all with d3.selectAll(".c3-bar"), - replace 'd3' with a particular svg selection if you have multiple charts - but as they are path elements rather than rects you'd have to do some parsing of the path's 'd' attribute (d for path info, not data) to get useful x/y coords out of them

Bear in mind in both cases the returned numbers will be offsets to some 'g' element container

Comment: I realized that I don't quite understand how you mean to do the second part of your answer. I found a way of getting the width of the bars by grabbing the chart's width and dividing by the number of data points, but what confuses me if how to get the height. Though, it seems you are suggesting a different method by grabbing each bar itself, do you have an example of how this is done? (I can't seem to find a valid source for this).

Comment: Here is an link to the fiddle i am working with: https://jsfiddle.net/cjrobinson/thuwbL96/

Comment: You can grab the bars with a d3 clause, but as they're not rects but paths they need a bit extra done to them, luckily getBoundingClientRect does that. `var bounds = [];
d3.selectAll(".c3-bar").each (function() {
    bounds.push (this.getBoundingClientRect());
});
console.log ("bounds:", bounds);` bounds now holds a list of the bars coordinates and width/heights.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/thuwbL96/9/ shows it adding the labels to the centre-ish bit of each bar (since it doesn't take into account the length of the label though it's a bit off). You could add svg 'text' elements instead of html 'p' elements and set their style to `text-anchor:middle` to avoid that difficulty.

Comment: It's also the case that if what you're wanting to do is shove the axis labels to the inside of the chart, you can do it with this code: `d3.select(".c3-axis-x")
    .attr("clip-path", null)
    .selectAll(".tick text")
        .style ("text-anchor", "start")
        .attr ("transform", "translate (10,0)")
;` see https://jsfiddle.net/thuwbL96/10/ . Hope that gives you a few ideas anyways.

Comment: Woah, this is great. I the bounds gives me the information I was looking for. The reason I had the text outside was because I plan on putting a html button element with background img and such on it and the rect that is being drawn is suppose to be the line that extends the width of the bar all the way to the button.